# Error (cannot auto create component) on creating custom component extending UriEndpointComponent

Tags: java, apache-camel

I create an component (used maven archetype generate) for an proprietary product. It seem to work very well (the auto mapping of uri parameters to fields is simply amazing). Now i read [about Annotations](http://camel.apache.org/endpoint-annotations.html) like `@UriParam` to optimize the generated maven site (i also annotated the Endpoint: `@UriEndpoint(scheme = "myScheme")`). On same page i read that is better to extend from `UriEndpointComponent`for this i had to add a constructor to component:

```
public mySchemeComponent(final Class<? extends Endpoint> endpointClass) {
    super(endpointClass);
}
```

But no it stopped working:
Pro... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: myScheme:... due to: Cannot auto create component: myScheme

So how to properly extend `UriEndpointComponent`
Or is there an example using this? i  found only [this](http://blog.javaforge.net/post/68180949840/creating-apache-camel-custom-component) but this is also "only" extending DefaultComponent.

Comment: better ask this on camel forum

Comment: i have much luck asking camel stuff here - got some answers from main developers here. Stackoverflow seem to be the number one source off all kind of (java)api/framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found an example myself (indirectly linked from [here](http://camel.apache.org/endpoint-annotations.html)):

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/trunk/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/timer/TimerComponent.java

The Trick is to provide a default constructor:

```
  public TimerComponent() {
        super(TimerEndpoint.class);
  }
```

In my case:

```
  public mySchemeComponent() {
        super(mySchemeEndpoint.class);
  }
```

With this it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Camel uses the service finder patter to locate the new added component.

Here the quote from the [Writing Components](http://camel.apache.org/writing-components.html)

> to support auto-discovery of your component add a file to
>   META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/FOO where FOO is the URI
>   scheme for your component and any related endpoints created on the
>   fly. The latter file should contain the definition of the component
>   class. For example if your component is implemented by the
>   com.example.CustomComponent class, the service file should contain the
>   following line - 
>      `class=com.example.CustomComponent` .

Comment: As i stated, all works fine by extending DefaultComponent (FOO file/scheme is in place) - project was built by maven archetype. I want to know how to write component by extending UriEndpointComponent - seems to be different

Comment: I see you point. Here is the tip, when you create a new component, you need to provide a component construction without any parameters. In this way camel can create the component instance for you.